# Dual boot Lenovo Y400 with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04.1 won't boot ubuntu since Nvidia driver update on WIndows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

Background: after some sketchy fixes, I managed six months ago to have my computer to dual boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04, with the fun perks of both OS having the time like 5 hours apart from one another: if I log in on Windows and then shut down and some time later log in ubuntu, the time is always wrong, and viceversa. Also, if I want to get in Windows, I have to select it in the grub, then enter, then the grub appears again and select it again, but only sometimes, most of the times, but sometimes I have to choose it just once.

So, 2 days ago the Nvidia driver wanted to update on windows (not the first time with ubuntu dual boot) and I did. The next day ubuntu hanged on "could not configure common clock", windows with only something wrong with the "Geforce experience" program, through which I update the nvidia drivers on windows, so I reinstalled it and everything seemed fine.

As today, I reverted to a past "geforce" windows driver and can only get to ubuntu to work if I get it to recovery mode, run dpkg, it apparently fails and does nothing, and then resume the recovery mode and finally I can do stuff here, but ubuntu fails to detect the second display I have.

Anyone knows something? I just found an unnanswered-bumped to oblivion link https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325384

Answer (score 0):

I think you can login to your linux in nomodeset:
when in grub, press e, then in the line that starts with linux, add "nomodeset" just before "quiet splash".
you will login to ubunutu and then update your kernel to the latest version.

I had some similar problems with some drivers that prevented my linux from booting. and also caused trouble while shutting down. managed to get in with nomodeset and after upgrading my kernel from 4.4.0 to v.4.8.3 the problems were solved.

Comment: is nomodeset instead of quiet splash? Also tried that. But if it is "nomodeset quiet splash" then I have to try it

Comment: It is "nomodeset quiet splash"

Comment: Ok, I tried that, hangs on black screen.
I can consistently get in if I do the recovery mode > run dpkg option > resume boot. So, although it doesn't download anything when running the dpkg, it does do "some things" like restarting kernel along a list of like 10 things, displaying "ok" everytime. I think the solution might be on this preparations to do the dpkg. Any ideas?